# What is the use of 5V pins on Raspberry Pi GPIO?

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio

On a Raspberry Pi, GPIO pins are 3V3 tolerant. And there are two 3V3 pins that we can use to play with GPIO (driving LEDs or sensing Buttons). But what is the purpose of the two 5V pins?

edit: I am talking about the pins specified in this official webpage - https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/

Comment: those are power pins not gpio pins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi board is powered off of 5V from the USB connector. The pins you see on the header can also power the Raspberry Pi in case you wanted to make a Hat that did something like [provide battery power to the Pi](https://uk.pi-supply.com/products/pijuice-standard). You could also make Hat's that use the 5V supply (sparingly) to power peripherals (like an [Arduino Hat](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1211.html)) and use level-shifters for communication back with the Pi.

5V is required for things like the HDMI, so it just makes sense to use 5V as the power input, and step it down to 3V3 for everything else. It also makes sense from a supply standpoint because phone chargers (that supply USB-5V) are cheap and in ready supply, so using one to power a super-cheap computer brings the total cost down to somebody who wants to get into it.

You can [look at the Raspberry Pi "schematics" here](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#schematics-and-mechanical-drawings) although they are pretty reduced since they don't release full schematics.